# Looping through method within an object Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel-4

I am trying to loop through a method I created for dates in my object. However, it's only looping the first results and I am not sure how I can make it loop through every result and apply accordingly.

**Date Method**

```
public function getDate($date) {
    $date = preg_replace('/,/', '', $date);

    $newDate = strtotime($date);

    $dateFormat = date('l: F d, Y',$newDate);   

    return $dateFormat;
}
```

**Controller calling the Model**

```
    public function showDashboard() {

        $pages = Pages::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->get();

//      foreach($pages as $page) {
//          $date = $this->getDate($page->created_at);
//      }


        //var_dump($date); die;

        return View::make('dashboard.index', ['pageTitle' => 'Dashboard','pages' => $pages]);
    }
```

dumping $date only returns one result which looks like the last date in the database table. If I put the dump inside the loop I only get the first result.

I tried applying the method directly to the Blade template `$this->getDate($page->created_at);` but returns an error stating it is not a defined method. The blade template is just a simple foreach loop that would show each record. What I want accomplished is foreach one of those created_at records I want the getDate method applied to it.

Answer (score 0):

You've not set $date as an array - its writing over itself each time..

```
public function showDashboard() {

    $pages = Pages::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->get();

    $date = array();

    foreach($pages as $page) {
        $date[] = $this->getDate($page->created_at);
    }


   var_dump($date); die;

    return View::make('dashboard.index', ['pageTitle' => 'Dashboard','pages' => $pages]);
}
```

Comment: OK, I did that but now how would I loop that $date when I already have a foreach loop with $pages? I get an array to string conversion failure each time